# how to give execute .sh file remotely on windows machine

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to execute a shell script on windows machine remotely using java (JSCH method to run remote command). It runs any given command on a command prompt on windows machine which is configured remotely.

Here, In the shell script, i should run a .ksh profile, and on that prompt, i should be running few commands. To do that, i have given code as below:

```
bash

. ./profile.ksh 

command1

command2
```

Here, to run a profile, i should start bash, and on that i should run the profile and run the command. But, this is not working as expected. It just connects to bash and leaves it there.

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: not clear what you are asking, but I hope you know there is not bash in windows unless you have installed something like cygwin or similar.

Comment: I have mks on windows

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a very in depth knowledge of linux, but I do know shell scripting to some extent. based on that here are the commands that should work for you:

First connect to linux server using ftp (you would need to supply your credentials):

```
ftp [IP Address of Linux]
```

Now to see which directory you are in use command `pwd`, then to change your present working directory make use of `cd` command.

Once you are in you desired directory set the mode to binary with this command:

```
bin
```

Then finally you can copy the file using this command:

```
get example.ls
```

If you want to download multiple files you can use `mget` command with wildcards (e.g. `mget *.ls` to donload all files with ls extension).

Hope this helps.